# Using POST for Wego flights API

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, post

I have been trying to implement the Wego flights API from http://support.wan.travel/hc/en-us/articles/200191669 which uses HTTP POST requests. I've only really ever used GET requests, so I did some reading on POST and so far I have not been able to find a way to post a request.

```
POST api.wego.com/flights/api/k/2/searches

{
"trips": [
{
  "departure_code": "SYD",
  "arrival_code": "LON",
  "outbound_date": "2014-01-24",
  "inbound_date": "2014-01-29"
}
],
"adults_count": 1
}
```

It requires `POST api.wego.com/flights/api/k/2/searches?api_key=your_secret_api_key&ts_code=your_s‌​ecret_ts_code`. What's wrong with this code?

```
 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://api.wego.com/flights/api/k/2/searches?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&ts_code=xxxxx"";
    var params = {
       "trips": [
          {
             "departure_code": "SYD",
             "arrival_code": "LON",
             "outbound_date": "2014-01-24",
             "inbound_date": "2014-01-29"
          }
       ],
       "adults_count": 1
    };
http.open("POST", url);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
http.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");


http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    alert(http.responseText);
}
}
var json = JSON.stringify(params);
http.send(json);
```

I'm getting `Invalid HTTP status code 403`

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: Invalid HTTP status code 403

Comment: i have been spend around about  hours , but at last i stuck here

Comment: does i am making wrong post request?

Comment: it requires in this format "POST api.wego.com/flights/api/k/2/searches?api_key=your_secret_api_key&ts_code=your_secret_ts_code"

Comment: Have you looked at the network console in your browser to see the request/response and their contents?

Comment: (Please don't post streams of comments here - if you have new information to add to the question, please edit the question - thanks).

Comment: Yes i have seen in console , this error come in console " Invalid HTTP status code 403"

Comment: Halfer can you guide me please?

Comment: Your `var url` line is terminated with two quote marks - is that a typo here or in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You must include your `api_key` and `ts_code` as GET parameters in request.

From http://support.wan.travel/hc/en-us/articles/200191669:

> In order to make requests to api.wego.com, your application must first obtain an api_key and a ts_code. Normally you should add your api_key and ts_code into query parameters.
>
> ```
> POST api.wego.com/flights/api/k/2/searches?api_key=your_secret_api_key&ts_code=your_secret_ts_code
> ```
>
> Please use your api_key and ts_code into all requests you make to api.wego.com and do not share them to anyone.
>
> Affiliate team is supporting api_key and ts_code, you can read more by the following link.

Comment: Getting same error after including api_KEY and ts_code ,

Comment: It says [here](http://support.wan.travel/hc/en-us/articles/200191669), that 403 error means "The limit of API calls is exceeded".

Comment: i am using same key and ts code for hostel api, that,s working fine, here is something wrong with code ? it is not an error that it is mentioning

Comment: any 1 help me i am stuck here

Comment: As @Gothdo said, you proubably exceeded API calls limit for that api_KEY and ts_code with yours fierce debugging attack on their server ^_^. Try to register new app for fresh api_KEY and ts_code.

Comment: now i am getting this error "Invalid HTTP status code 404"